# Matplotlib BarPlot update in tkinter frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

i am trying to update a graph in tkinter .
To swap window in tkinter i use button and pack_forget()
But when re-opening the graph i have the following message:

```
MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Adding an axes using the same arguments as a previous axes currently reuses the earlier instance.  In a future version, a new instance will always be created and returned.  Meanwhile, this warning can be suppressed, and the future behavior ensured, by passing a unique label to each axes instance.
```

Each time the graph data change , so it must be updated. I know i have to use something like plt.clear() to erase an re-initialise the plot but i don't know how, can you help me?

```
#########GRAPH FRAME CONTENT##########
matplotlibframe = Frame(root,bd=2)
fig = Figure(figsize = (9, 15),dpi = 80)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig,master = matplotlibframe)

Return_Btn = Button(matplotlibframe,text='Return',command=machine)

def checkstock():
    global canvas
    global fig
    hide_frame()
    matplotlibframe.pack()
    #Tell server i want to check the stock
    tell_Stock = pickle.dumps("Graph")
    client_socket.sendall(tell_Stock)
    #Getting the stock data
    Stock_status = client_socket.recv(1024)
    Stock_status = pickle.loads(Stock_status)
    
    plot1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

    canvas.draw()

    x = []
    y = []
    colors = []
    for item in range(len(Stock_status)):
        x.append(Stock_status[item][0])
        y.append(Stock_status[item][1])

    for loop in range(9):
        if (loop % 2) == 0:
            colors.append('#FCAB64') 
        else:
            colors.append('#A1FCDF')

    plot1.barh(x,y,height=0.5,color=colors)
    plot1.set_title('Stock')

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=LEFT)

    Return_Btn.pack(side=RIGHT)
```

machine() contain a lots of things.
hide_frame() contain .pack_forget() for all other frame of my GUI
to swap frame , i do:
in machine():

```
def machine():
    #plt.close(fig)
    hide_frame()
    frame.pack(side=LEFT,fill="none",expand=TRUE)
    frameRight.pack(side=LEFT,fill="none",expand=TRUE,ipadx=50)
```

In hide_frame():

```
def hide_frame():
    frame.pack_forget()
    frameRight.pack_forget()
    frameConfirm.pack_forget()
    matplotlibframe.pack_forget()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack_forget()
    framePay.pack_forget()
```

Comment: You are asking two different things: `To swap window in tkinter i use button and pack_forget()` which raises the warning, and `Each time the graph data change , so it must be updated`. Which of the two you need help with? A dynamic layout or plot?

Comment: Okay so I need help with erasing and redrawing the plot when I swap window, which is the same as when I click a button , doing my function and forgetting the other windows.

Comment: Could you add the code for `machine` and `hide_frame` then? I'm guessing those are the function to swap window? If not, add the code for the swap please.

Comment: yes of course hide_frame is used in all my other command at start to forget the other frame .